# Stop $_GET being processed after reload

Tags: php, html, unlink

I'm creating a link which appends a $_GET variable to the end of it for use of deleting files / other PHP tasks.

```
<a href="test.php?delete_file=<?php echo $filename; ?>">Delete file</a>
```

Part of my PHP code looks for the variable and if it exists, it runs the unset function to remove the file, but when I reload the webpage, it obviously tries to remove the file again. Is there any way to remove the $_GET after it has been run once to stop the processing after a refresh?

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['delete_file'])) {
    if (file_exists($full_path.$_GET['delete_file'])) {
        unlink($_GET['delete_file']);
    } else {
        echo "File ".$full_path.$_GET['delete_file']." doesn't exist";
    }
}
?>

<a href="test.php?delete_file=<?php echo $filename; ?>">Delete file</a>
```

Comment: You can add this `header("Location: test.php");` after `unlink`.

Comment: I hope you have stronger security measures in place, so that only very very very trusted people can delete files, and not in a CSRF way ...

Comment: @johannes, yes, thats all taken care of in the script as well as only certain users getting this permission (super users)

Comment: @SahilGulati Thats a potential yes, I presume that just reloads the page again, so it would in reality be two reloads (1 when the link is clicked and another when the unlink is done).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ajax to remove files so it won't refresh.

```
<a href="javascript:deletefile('<?php echo $filename; ?>')">Delete file</a>
 <script>
        function deletefile(filename){
                var data = {delete_file:filename };
                $.ajax({ 
                        url: 'delete.php',
                        type: 'post',
                        data: data,
                        success: function(response) {
                            // .. do something with response ..
                            // you can use window.location to refresh page   
                           // or if you have js method to refresh page. you can call it here
                        }
                }); 
        }
        </script>
```

In php file you can retrive with post

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['delete_file'])) {
    if (file_exists($full_path.$_POST['delete_file'])) {
        unlink($_POST['delete_file']);
    } else {
        echo "File ".$full_path.$_POST['delete_file']." doesn't exist";
    }
}
?>
```

But as the commenters say this is open to potential security issues. You need to take care of security if you use this approach in production.